# Cannot boot live into linux from USB on Asus ROG laptop

Tags: fedora, boot, uefi, boot-loader, live-usb

I'm trying to dual boot on my Asus ROG Flow x13 laptop. I want to dual boot Fedora Workstation, but I'm having an issue where whenever I select `Start Fedora-Workstation-Live 35` the screen will just go black, then after ~20 seconds, it will 'restart' (return to POST).

My laptop has a AMD Ryzen 9 5000 series CPU, with an Nvidia RTX 3050ti GPU. (Yea, I know Nvidia and Linux don't get along well- but i know it's possible)

I have tried all of the following:

1. Turned off secure boot
2. Turned off fast boot, as well as #1
3. Tried booting into 'simple graphics' mode
4. Tried changing the boot commands: removing `quiet`, adding `verbose`, adding `nomodeset`, adding `nvidia.modeset=0`
5. Tried booting into a different distro (Pop!_OS, still had the same issue)
6. Turning off drive encryption (BitLocker) in Windows 10

But to no avail. Is it something related to UEFI? Or is the GPU completely screwing me over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your BIOS version is 408 or 409, upgrade to 410 (or downgrade to 407).

Comment: My bios version is 409, so i will try updating it, thank you

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much